# Content Type Field value in variable

Tags: nodes, theming

I've created a content type with some fields like `link` , `address`. And I did content-type node theming with name **node--machine-name.tpl.php** and all fields are printed by this code

```
<?php print render($content['content']); ?>
```

or individual fields like this

```
<?php print render($content['field_link_url']); ?> 
<?php print render($content['body']); ?>
```

But I want to save the **link** field in a variable, which will be used in various ways.

I just want this **field_link_url** field to not be **printed** but to be stored in a variable

**What I Tried**

1. echo $link =  $field_link_url['und'][0]['value'];
2. echo $link = $content['field_link_url']['und'][0]['value'];

Apart from that I got the message with all the array fields with this

```
`drupal_set_message("<pre>". print_r($node,true) . "</pre>");`
```

which gave me this..

```
stdClass Object
(
[vid] => 51
[uid] => 1
[title] => Run Tests on the Cloud. No Software or Hardware Required!
[log] => 
[status] => 1
[comment] => 1
[promote] => 0
[sticky] => 0
[nid] => 51
[type] => landing_pages
[language] => und
[created] => 1392994690
[changed] => 1393072611
[tnid] => 0
[translate] => 0
[revision_timestamp] => 1393072611
[revision_uid] => 1
[body] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                            No software or hardware to buy or maintain. 
                        [summary] => 
                        [format] => full_html
                        [safe_value] => 
                            No software or hardware to buy or maintain.


                        [safe_summary] => 
                    )

            )

    )


[field_link_title] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => START A FREE TRAIL
                        [format] => 
                        [safe_value] => START A FREE TRAIL
                    )

            )

    )

[field_link_url] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => http://xyz.displaybox.in/why-xyz/easy-to-manage-your-tests
                        [format] => 
                        [safe_value] =>  http://xyz.displaybox.in/why-xyz/easy-to-manage-your-tests
                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On template file  **node--machine-name.tpl.php** $node is an object. So you can access its value like $node->nid as node id.
So if you want to access **field_link_url** field value directly then use following code . `$link = $node->field_link_url['und'][0]['value']`

Answer (score 0):

> echo $link = $content['field_link_url']['und'][0]['value'];

This way must be correct!
Check *field_link_url* key in *content* variable with dsm or kpr fucntion.

And try to get *field_link_url* value from this key.